# Why does this this node js load test start slowing down at 60 rps?

Tags: node.js, load-testing

I'm load testing my nodejs rest api.

I have an endpoint which goes to mongo db and returns about 94k to the client. This endpoint hits mongo 5 times on 5 different collections each time it is called.

here is some psuedo code of the function being called:

```
function getLevels(teamId, userId, from, to) {
    var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        myService.hitMongo1(teamId, userId).then(function (state) {
            ...do some stuff with the result
            var collection = ...get collection obj...
            collection.find(q, pr).toArray().then(function (docs) {
                if (docs) {
                    ...do some stuff with results...
                    var proms = [ // 4 parallel mongo hits as promises, they all function directly on the docs array
                        mongHit11(docs, state),
                        mongoHit12(teamId, userId, docs),
                        mongoHit13(teamId, docs, state),
                        mongoHit14(teamId, userId, docs)
                    ];
                    Promise.all(proms).then(function(resolves){
                        resolve({levels: docs});
                    });
                } else {
                    resolve({levels: []});
                }
            }).catch(function (e) {
                console.log(e.stack);
                resolve({levels: []});
            });
        });
    });
    return p;
}
```

when i loadtest it (with the loadtest npm package) i get the following results. you'll notice that running 50 requests/sec will return with an avg response time of 30ms, but when run at 60 reqs/sec the response time starts growing and growing, even to 20 secs, and will keep growing until the test is stopped. there must be something in the basic functioning of node or mongoto explain this behaviour but i have no clue what:

```
✗ loadtest -c 1 --rps 60 http://localhost:3000/v1/game/sss/van/571e1a5de06c46b65599fa00/levels/1/55
[Mon Apr 25 2016 16:59:48 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 0, requests per second: 0, mean latency: 0 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 16:59:53 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 212, requests per second: 42, mean latency: 420 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 16:59:58 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 435, requests per second: 45, mean latency: 1470 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:00:03 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 626, requests per second: 38, mean latency: 3060 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:00:08 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 822, requests per second: 39, mean latency: 4760 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:00:13 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 1024, requests per second: 40, mean latency: 6640 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:00:18 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 1207, requests per second: 37, mean latency: 8360 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:00:23 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 1395, requests per second: 38, mean latency: 10150 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:00:28 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 1526, requests per second: 26, mean latency: 12570 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:00:33 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 1664, requests per second: 28, mean latency: 15200 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:00:38 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 1821, requests per second: 31, mean latency: 17960 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:00:43 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 1986, requests per second: 33, mean latency: 20460 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:00:48 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 2172, requests per second: 37, mean latency: 22510 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:00:53 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 2390, requests per second: 44, mean latency: 24340 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:00:58 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 2575, requests per second: 37, mean latency: 26050 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:01:03 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 2774, requests per second: 40, mean latency: 27610 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:01:08 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 2930, requests per second: 31, mean latency: 29420 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:01:13 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 3104, requests per second: 35, mean latency: 31040 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:01:18 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 3294, requests per second: 38, mean latency: 33420 ms

✗ loadtest -c 1 --rps 50 http://localhost:3000/v1/game/sss/van/571e1a5de06c46b65599fa00/levels/1/55
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:01:32 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 0, requests per second: 0, mean latency: 0 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:01:37 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 201, requests per second: 40, mean latency: 30 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:01:42 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 450, requests per second: 50, mean latency: 20 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:01:47 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 700, requests per second: 50, mean latency: 30 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:01:52 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 950, requests per second: 50, mean latency: 70 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:01:57 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 1200, requests per second: 50, mean latency: 30 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:02:02 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 1450, requests per second: 50, mean latency: 30 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:02:07 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 1701, requests per second: 50, mean latency: 30 ms
[Mon Apr 25 2016 17:02:12 GMT+0300 (IDT)] INFO Requests: 1951, requests per second: 50, mean latency: 30 ms
```

i'm running it on a macbook pro, with everything including mongo running locally. does anyone have any idea what could be causing the significant slow down at 60 rps?

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it not about programming. The question is about how to interpret test results but there is very little context on what the test data means. Other possible reason for closure include "Too broad" and "Primarily opinion based".

Comment: what?! are you serious? you could just say that i should add some context if thats what you need. and how is this not programming based??

Comment: i've just added some code, and narrowed the question down

Comment: Please read the [help] pages about what is on topic for Stack Overflow and also on how to write a good question.

Comment: ok i read it, and after having added some code i think the question qualifies and if answered can benefit other users. i'll try rewording the question itself if that helps, but the basic thing i want to know is what does it mean when a nodejs loadtest suddently starts showing a linear slowdown after a certain threshold of hits pers sec is crossed. what does it mean?